# Name variables with names given in a list using a loop

Tags: r, excel, list, loops, variable-assignment

I have two databases in an excel file, and each is in a separate excel sheet, respectively NOMINAL and REAL. Then I want to upload these databases into R using a loop as follows:

```
library(readxl)
mylist <-list("NOMINAL", "REAL")
for (page in mylist) {
  page <- read_excel("C:/Users/Cys/OneDrive/Documents/Database/BIS-MLTI-FX.xlsx", sheet = page)
}
```

When I run this loop, I'm having the last database (REAL) with the name "page" as the assignment is not allowing to name my databases with the names in the list provided.

My question is how should I write this loop in order to assign to my databases the names in the list?

Comment: Have a look at the [assign function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/assign).

Comment: No, please *don't* use `assign`, its use typically indicates making more work for yourself. There is another problem here: you are looping with `page` as character, and then you assign the return value to the same variable `page` (which is subsequently discarded). This should be something like `out <- lapply(mylist, function(pg) read_excel("...", sheet=pg))`, and now you have two frames in a single list.

Comment: (After that, you can do something like `names(out) <- mylist` so that `out$REAL` or `out[["REAL"]]` give you the respective tables.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in a loop, then you first have to create a list object. Then you can assign elements to that list.

```r
sheet_names <- c("NOMINAL", "REAL")
sheet_dfs <- list()

for (page in sheet_names) {
  sheet_dfs[page] <- 
    read_excel("C:/Users/Cys/OneDrive/Documents/Database/BIS-MLTI-FX.xlsx", 
    sheet = page)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I tried exactly :
sheet_names <- c("NOMINAL", "REAL")
sheet_dfs <-list()

for (page in sheet_names) {
  sheet_dfs[page] <- read_excel("C:/Users/Cys/OneDrive/Documents/Database/BIS-MLTI-FX.xlsx",  sheet = page)
}. But I am still having the same issue.